# Locks on Radix tree

Tags: c, multithreading, tree

I am working on adding and removing nodes on Radix tree using multithreading. How should I lock the tree? Do I need to lock individual nodes? Also is the latency high if I lock the entire tree?  I am using C language.

Comment: Only you can answer this question by trying it out and profiling. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: This is definitely too broad for one question. Do some research on locking mechanisms and come back when you have a more specific question or need help troubleshooting a specific piece of code. Questions about speed will almost always be met with comments asking if you profiled your code, so profile first, then come ask about the results if they don't make sense.